# What is the function E(x)?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, conjectures, riemann-hypothesis

I’m an electrical engineering student getting a minor in math. I recently started my first pure math class and my professor proposed something interesting on the board. I don’t remember exactly what he said about it but he mentioned it was something like the Riemann hypothesis. He that pi(x) = li(x) + E(x) along with other stuff. I understand what li(x) and pi(x) are but what exactly is E(x)?(I attached  a picture of what was on the board) [Picture of board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5lzc.jpg)

Comment: $E(x)$ is *defined* by your equation.

Comment: Also, it is the “*E*rror” of $\pi(x)\approx\text{li}(x)$

Comment: "Also"? this is just a (less precise) reformulation. Oh sorry I just understood you were justifying the letter $E.$

Comment: If the Riemann hypothesis is true, there is a much better known upper bound for the error we make if we replace $\pi(x)$ by $li(x)$.